# About a equality of calculus.

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus

Im enconter a proof of a identity about the Beta function, however im strugling in a step
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{x+y+1} \left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^x dt
&= \left[\frac{-(1-t)^{x+y-1}}{x+y}\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^x\right]^1_0 + \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x+y}t^{x-1}(t-1)^{y-1} dt\end{align}$$

Could someone elaborate why this is true?

Comment: Looks like integration by parts with some substitution.

Comment: This post needs lots of improvements one you should state the full identity that's needing to be proved and your initial progress on the proof or understanding of your question

Comment: Its a proof about the Beta function , $$B(x+1, y) = \left ( \frac{ x}{x+y} \right ) B(x,y) $$ its probably a simple proof and its the only step i dont understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u=\left({t\over 1-t}\right)^x$ and $v=(1-t)^{x+y-1}$

Its $$\int_a^b u\cdot v dt=\left[u\int vdt\right]_a^b+\int_a^b {du\over dt}\left(\int vdt\right)dt$$